# displaying ad(Top or bottom) in layout which is in scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview, admob

I am trying to add ads to my layout on top of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feststatic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/festname"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/festival"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#C2DFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daystatic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/weekday"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#C2DFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthstatic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/month"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#C2DFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fulldatestatic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fulldate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#C2DFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descstatic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/desc"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#C2DFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>



 </ScrollView>
```

The above is my Xml layout file but when i run it  i get this error
"Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <320, 50>, Has: <310, 1073741823>"
  I didn't give any padding to the scrollview.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad..I gave padding to linear layout...I removed it and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

End the file with `</ScrollView>`, just below `</LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks.I have the scrollview end statement.

Comment: Try removing all the text views first. if problem still persist, it might be the ad.

Comment: can i fix the ad at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes. Create a RelativeLayout as parent of scrollview. then put the admob child of the layout instead of scrollview and set layout to bottom.

Comment: @Hend: thank you..it works..to fix it i use your idea..I also use  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
in ads Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a relativeLayout instead? Also consider reading this:

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/incorporating-android-admob-ads-into.html

Answer (score 0):

From: @Hend Create a RelativeLayout as parent of scrollview. Then put the admob view as a child of the RelativeLayout instead of scrollview and use **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** in it(admov view).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGeneralHeader"
            style="@style/heading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="General Info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLine1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGeneralHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGenealDescription"
            style="@style/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewGeneralHeader"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Description" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLine2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGenealDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDisplayHeader"
            style="@style/heading_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewGeneralHeader"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine2"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Display Info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLine3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDisplayHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDisplayDescription"
            style="@style/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewGeneralHeader"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewLine3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Description" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLine4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDisplayDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14e2f8fe3af5a6"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView></RelativeLayout>
```